# "Feel bad about someone" versus "feel bad for someone"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions, collocation

Does the sentence "I feel bad about you" have the same meaning as "I feel bad for you"?

Comment: No. The former has a condescending tone while the latter has a sympathetic tone. It would be appreciated if you included the research that was done before posting the question.

Answer (score 2):

"I feel bad about you" says that the person who is saying this does not have a good feeling and shows negative emotion about the person "**YOU**" while second sentence "I feel bad for you" says that whatever the person has heard about the person is not good shows sympathetic emotion.